# Why does Skia include a Forth interpreter?

Tags: forth, skia

Why does [Skia](https://skia.org/) include a [Forth interpreter](https://github.com/google/skia/tree/master/forth)?

Comment: This question imho can be understood in many ways. Examples: "Why a forth and not a lua/<your prefered interpreter> instead?" "Why an interpreter at all?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Forth interpreter inclusion was originally going to be a mini-scripting language to call Skia.

Mike Reed, [software engineer and manager](http://www.dailytarheel.com/article/2014/04/google-moves-its-chapel-hill-location-to-franklin-street) (second line of article) of one of the Google offices, confirmed that [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skia-discuss/joAyAl1f6Sw).